# NHibernate: Updates in one session don't get reflected in another open session

Tags: .net, wpf, nhibernate

This is a WPF app. I use one session per presenter. The user navigates from one presenter to another but usually no more than 2 levels deep:

1. Open Presenter1 (Session1) -> Displays a list of entities
2. Navigate to Presenter2 (Session2) (Presenter1 and Session1 are still alive)
3. Presenter2 (Session2) -> Edits an entity
4. Navigate back to Presenter1. Session2 is closed and changes are persisted in the database
5. Presenter1 reloads list of entities but the change made in step 3 is not there

How can I solve this scenario?

Comment: How do you know that the changes are persisted at the db level, after the Session2 is closed, but before the Session one reloads? How have you verified this? How are you reading these sessions/data from nHibernate - any code you can put up?

Comment: I know that it's in the DB because when I'm back on Presenter1 I run a query in the DB itself and the data is updated there. I'll update the question showing how I read the data, but I've tried several things and none gives me back the correct data (Session.CreateCriteria, Session.QueryOver, even Session.Get)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because the Session includes what is commonly referred to as the first-level cache. It simply contains all entities the Session has "seen" during it's lifespan, in order to avoid re-fetching them from the database.

You can use `session.Clear()` to clear the session before making any queries. If you do this in your presenter after each navigation action, you should be OK.

Another approach is to define a SessionManager class that manages your Session so the two presenters share their Session. This might be the best solution, if you can find some way to define the lifespan of one Session (I wouldn't recommend keeping the same Session around for the entire program execution).

Comment: Session.Clear() That's it! I have to design the SessionManager but for now it will suffice.

Comment: Session.Clear is usually bad design. You should Refresh() updated entities only.

Comment: Thanks Diego. In fact, it fits much better my current design as I receive an UpdatedEntity event in Presenter1 so I can simply refresh it.

Comment: So after calling `CoolThingDao.Save(newCoolThing)` and `CoolThingDao.Flush()`, you also have to call `CoolThingDao.Session.Clear()`. Good to know!